# Determine lisp object size in memory?

Tags: debugging, performance

**Q:** how does one determine how much memory an arbitrary lisp object is consuming?

Example use case: I've got a hash table holding lists of strings.  I'm curious about how much memory it's using.

Comment: I think that the problem is in determining what to count. Just the object fields (but not the values in those fields)? Do methods count? With "simple" objects like the hash-table, you could make an educated guess: say, count the total length of the keys, count the number of keys and multiply it with log base two and a size of a key - this would give you roughly the size of the memory used to store the keys, but as to the values - depends on what you count.

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64776/15748

Answer (score 2):

How to determine the size?  By looking at the C source code whee those objects are defined (e.g. `src/lisp.h`).

IIRC in the case of a hash-table, you should count more or less 6 words (32 or 64bit, depending on your system) per element in the hash-table.