# Is there any way to get the memory size (usage) of a Lisp variable/value?

Tags: debugging, performance

Basically `sizeof` for lists, hashmaps, etc., with nested structures.

I could of course disable garbage collection and then compare numbers from [memory usage functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Memory-Usage.html) before and after allocation, getting vaguely informative but imprecise numbers—due to probably also having created intermediate vars.

But maybe there's a method that involves less approximate guesswork and more straightforward calculation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine lisp object size in memory?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12296/determine-lisp-object-size-in-memory)

Comment: @Basil No, “look through the source and figure it out” is a non-answer. Why would I need StackExchange if I were ready to dig for all the type sizes and then calculate the sum myself?

Comment: I was just linking to a similar, older question.  The "Does this answer your question?" text was added by StackExchange.  My preferred answer is below, of course: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64776/15748

Comment: @Basil Ah, sorry. I had an inkling that it might be the case, from the awkwardly wooden language of the comment text. And didn't notice that you're the person who answered this very question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any way to get the memory size/usage of a variable?

Emacs 28 adds a more fine-grained memory usage reporting command than was previously available:

```
** New command 'memory-report'.
This command opens a new buffer called "*Memory Report*" and gives a
summary of where Emacs is using memory currently.
```

One of its subroutines is `memory-report-object-size`:

```el
(defun memory-report-object-size (object)
  "Return the size of OBJECT in bytes."
  (unless memory-report--type-size
    (memory-report--garbage-collect))
  (memory-report--object-size (make-hash-table :test #'eq) object))
```

For example:

```el
(let ((table (make-hash-table)))
  (mapcar #'memory-report-object-size
          (list (cons nil nil)
                (list nil nil)
                table
                (cons table table)
                (list table table))))
;; => (16 32 1056 1072 1088)
```

Comment: Interesting. I have to wonder now if 28 also changes memory usage of any types.

Comment: From the first two we can infer that a cons cell requires 16 bytes and nil values 0 (cons + 2nil = 16; 2cons + 3 nil = 32).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It's common in many Lisp implementations for `nil` to be implemented as an immediate value, so it doesn't take any space itself.

Comment: And this is also true for fixnums.